# Is there any way to replace repetitive try catch blocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, model-view-controller, try-catch

In my first asp.net mvc application I'm handling errors with try-catch blocks and returning specific messages to the user as Httpstatuscode.
In every crud operation there is same code block.

I tried using exceptionhandler attribute but I couldn't manage to return status code or custom message with it.

Is there any way to replace these try catch blocks on every function and return a message to user?

This is what I tried :

```
public class ExceptionHandlerFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{ 
    private ILogger _logger;

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        _logger = new NLogLogger();
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var message = filterContext.Exception;

            _logger.Log(Business.Enums.LogLevel.Error, string.Concat("/",controller,"/",action), message);

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "Error"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example method :

```
  public HttpStatusCodeResult Create(Product product)
    {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);

        try
        {
            _productService.Create(product);

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception) { return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); }

    }
```

I would like to replace repetitive try-catch blocks for a better code.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your methods with something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Tries the specified action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
    public static HttpStatusCodeResult Try(Action action, ModelState model)
    {
        if (!model.IsValid) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
        try
        {
            action();
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception) { return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); }
    }
```

And you can use your Try:

```
 public HttpStatusCodeResult Create(Product product)
 {
    return Try(()=> {
        _productService.Create(product);
    }, ModelState);
 }
```

[Here an wrapper example in github](https://github.com/JSMontoya/og.zoo/blob/master/2.Application/OG.Zoo.Application.Services/Generics/ApplicationUtil.cs)

[And the call of that try](https://github.com/JSMontoya/og.zoo/blob/master/2.Application/OG.Zoo.Application.Services/Security/UserApplication.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `HttpStatusCodeResult` for `Result` property of `filterContext`:

`filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);`